# Selenium not able to find elements

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver

Selenium is not able to find elements.
I am trying to find an id with PageHeader_logourl
But it's throwing Unable to locate an element with xpath expression.

Am I doing anything wrong

Here is the html code

```
<DIV id="page" class="page">
<DIV id="wrapper" class="wrapper">
    <DIV id="header" class="header">
        <TABLE width="100%" height="40" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" ID="Table2">
            <TR>
                <TD>
                    <TABLE height="40" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" ID="Table3">
                        <TR>
                            <TD><a href="http://www.scania.com" id="PageHeader_logoUrl" tabIndex="-1" target="_blank"><span id="HeaderLogoImage"></span></a></TD>
                            <TD valign="middle"><label id="PageHeader_lblProjectName" class="projectname">Scania Trucks – SSS 4 TestR1</label></TD>
```

Here is the snapshot of my selenium code:

```
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='UserNameInputText']")).sendKeys(username);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='Brand']")).sendKeys(password);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='CmdLogin']")).click();
    Assert.assertTrue(isuserloggedin(),"Login failed");
}

public boolean isuserloggedin()
{
    boolean flag = false;
    if (!driver.findElements(By.id("Cancel")).isEmpty() || 
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id=['PageHeader_logoUrl']")).isDisplayed());
    {
        flag = true;
    }


return flag;
```

Comment: Why don't you use `findelement(By.id('PageHeader_logoUrl')`?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an error of one extra [ in your `xpath`. You may want to try this  "//*[@id='PageHeader_logoUrl']"

You can look for more strategies [here](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/choosing-effective-xpath/)

Comment: What about "//*[@id='PageHeader_logoUrl']" ?

Answer (score 0):

Try search the parent element first:

```
by.Xpath("//table[@id='Table3']//a[@id='PageHeader_logoUrl']")
```

Also my suggestion (again) is to search the nearest/ parent element first and debug if you actually get the element that you wanted.